# App service plan calculation for multiple app in single app service plan and its scalability

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-app-service-plans

I know that there is already some question around this. I am still confused about pricing.

My scenario is following

- 1 App Service Plan ( Standard s2 , 3.5 RAM , 50 GB size)
- 6 App Service belong to that plan.

Does it means that all 6 apps share 3.5 RAM and 50 GB storage or each app has 3.5 GB RAM and 50 GB ?

Also plan states that 10 instance auto scale. What does this actually mean ? Each app service scale at moment or each app service scale separately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All 6 apps would share the [same resources](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/overview-hosting-plans):

> When you create an app in App Service, it is put into an App Service plan. When the app runs, it runs on all the VM instances configured in the App Service plan. If multiple apps are in the same App Service plan, they all share the same VM instances. If you have multiple deployment slots for an app, all deployment slots also run on the same VM instances. If you enable diagnostic logs, perform backups, or run WebJobs, they also use CPU cycles and memory on these VM instances.

As far as scaling that is done at the app service plan so again the scale will apply to all app services:

> In this way, the App Service plan is the scale unit of the App Service apps. If the plan is configured to run five VM instances, then all apps in the plan run on all five instances. If the plan is configured for autoscaling, then all apps in the plan are scaled out together based on the autoscale settings.

Comment: Thanks for answer .... Just want to clarify that if I go for plan with autoscale to 10 instance so that 10 instance is free or each instance cost separately.

Comment: Each vm instance it is scaled to is charged. If trying to auto scale ensure you have a scale up and a corresponding scale down rule